# Finding Cubic Polynomials

Tags: matlab, octave, polynomials

I have an equation: `y=ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d` and the list of values `x = 1, 2, 3, 4` when `y = 3, 4, 3, -6` respectively. In Octave, I want to:

(a)  Set  up  a  system  of  four  equations  involving a, b, c and d. For example, substituting (x, y) = (1,3) into the polynomial gives the equation 3 = a + b + c + d.

(b)  Solve the system in (a).

I've been trying to find how to do this for three hours and found nothing. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks.

pstscrpt - I have to do everything in Octave, even though I could find it by hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Written without any `;` at end of assignements so you can see what is going on.
You problem is basically a linear system in the variables [a,b,c,d]'=z
So you need to build a system A*z=y, where A is a matrix 4x4, y and z are column vector size 4

```
x=[1,2,3,4]'
y=[3,4,3,-6]'
A=zeros(4,4)

for i=1:4
 A(i,:)= [ x(i)^3, x(i)^2, x(i), 1]
endfor 

z=A\y
```

the outcome will be

```
z =

  -1.00000
   5.00000
  -7.00000
   6.00000
```

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab: start by just substituting the different values of `x` and `y` you wrote in the expression  `a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d = y` as:

```
syms a b c d
eqn1 = a*1^3 + b*1^2 + c*1^1 +d ==  3 ;
eqn2 = a*2^3 + b*2^2 + c*2^1 +d ==  4 ;
eqn3 = a*3^3 + b*3^2 + c*3^1 +d ==  3 ;
eqn4 = a*4^3 + b*4^2 + c*4^1 +d == -6 ;
```

Then Use `equationsToMatrix` to convert the equations into the form `AX = B`. The second input to `equationsToMatrix` specifies the independent variables in the equations.:

```
 [A,B] = equationsToMatrix([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4], [a, b, c,d ])
```

and the solution for a,b,c,d is:

```
 X = linsolve(A,B)
```

you can also use if you want

```
sol = solve([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4], [a, b, c,d ])
```